# Утечка памяти - как узнать число потоков в приложении ?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, memory

В приложении используются потоки для обработки входящих подключений и один поток-очередь для записи в БД. Наблюдается утечка памяти. Так как кроме потоков и их внутренних объектов ничего не создается есть подозрение что потоки отработав продолжают занимать память.

Как узнать число потоков в приложении ?

Comment: Может куму пригодятся ссылки:
* Управление временем существования объектов (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc163316.aspx)

Comment: По старой ссылке почему-то больше нет статьи. Вот новая: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384186(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Для `.NET >= 3.5` число *активных* потоков можно получить следующим образом:

  ```
  using (var currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess())
  {
      return process.Threads
          .OfType<System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread>()
          .Where(t => t.ThreadState == System.Diagnostics.ThreadState.Running)
          .Count();
  }
  ```
- Насчет утечек памяти - рекомендую просмотреть вот [**этот тред,**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331389/c-sharp-thread-not-releasing-memory) из которого можно выцепить тезис про то, что доверять стандартным средствам при мониторинге состояния `GC` нельзя.

> - Так что либо `"Trust The Garbage Collector",` либо используйте специализированные утилиты для профайлинга.
> - Интуиция почему-то подсказывает мне, что вы опирались на значения из разряда `Working Set / Private Working Set` в таскменеджере, хотя, разумеется, могу ошибаться.

Comment: Да, именно на *Рабочий набор / Частный рабочий набор* смотрел (в *Диспетчере задач Windows)* - оба со временем растут, через 2-3 дня набирается чуть больше 300Мб, от стартовых 32-36Мб.  
Спасибо за ссылку - посмотрю что будет происходить в [Process Explorer][1].

  [1]: technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: Нужно еще помнить о том, что если memory pressure нет, то GC и не будет стремиться освобождать память.

Comment: Разве в таких случаях не нужно использовать HandleCollector (см. [Управление временем существования объектов][1]) ?

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc163316.aspx